# Joining three large tables in GBQ causes query overload

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a simple query:

```
select
  farm_fingerprint(REPLACE(concat(coalesce(CAST(UPPER(Field1) AS STRING),''), coalesce(Field2 ,'')),' ','')) as PROPERTYID
  from `mother-216719.DS1.TBL1` M
  Join `mother-216719.DS1.TBL2` B  on B.id = M.Internal_FA_Property_Ref_ID
  join `mother-216719.DS2.TBLA` T on T.ATTOM_ID = B.ATTOM_ID
LIMIT 10
```

the join fields are int64 against int64.  TBL2 (B) is a bridge table between TBL1 and TBLA.  The The intent is to bring fields together between TBL1 and TBLA for a consolidated fields.

The job Execution Details indicate significant Repartition sessions and while the query estimate indicates the query should process 17.5Gb however the job execution indicates 40.5Gb shuffled.  when I `LIMIT 10` it takes 3 minutes.  if I remove the `LIMIT`, the query runs for six hours and then fails.

How do I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: You should use `WHERE` to filter out only data you need.

Comment: I would normally, however, I want ALL the records.

Comment: how big the data is?

Comment: TBL1: 469Mil; TBL2 23Mil; TBLA 131Mil

Comment: what is mill? number of records? how about sizes? also what the nature of those joining keys? are they unique/distinct  in each table or duplicate ? etc. give us more info? the more the better

Comment: Mil = Million records.  Here are the sizes TBL1 331.4 GB, TBL2 527.06 MB, TBLA 182.51 GB.

Comment: how about keys? - check more Q in my comment

Comment: The keys are all INTEGER so no conversions there.  The idea is to go from TBLA to TBL1 via the B(ridge) TBL2 table.  They may not be unique.  There may be a chance at duplicates.

Comment: they are unique in the TBL2 table.  They may not be unique in the other two.

Comment: Check that.  The bridge table has key pairs where one key matches TBLA and the other Match TBL1.  The key pairs are unique, but one of the keys could be duplicate.  TBLA key may not be unique, and TBL1 also may have duplicates.

Comment: `"They may not be unique"` - so this would explain the issue! and usually there is no much sense in doing such joins in this case (your case might be exception though). I think you need to try revisit your requirements - what and why you do

Comment: so the problem is that I need to create a dataset between TBL1 and TBLA.  I need some fields from each one.

Comment: quick recommendation - i feel like joining for third table should be not just between T and B but also between M and T like something like this  - `ON T.ATTOM_ID = B.ATTOM_ID AND T.some_field = M.some_field` - otherwise you are doing cross product which cause the problem.So that second condition will resolve/eliminate  cross product

Comment: obviously consider partitioning by integer field - [Creating and using integer range partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-integer-range-partitions)

Comment: sorry - one more - what the point in `CAST(UPPER(Field1) AS STRING)` ? if you use UPPER it means that Field1 is already STRING - so why to CAST - not big deal - but string operations by themselves are relatively expensive so should better avoid not needed expenses

Comment: Thanks.  I’ll look into that.  I’ll study the integers partitioning as well.  This might be something I’ll need to reduce the effect size.  I appreciate it.  Trying it now.

Comment: I would consider to look at `JOIN` clause usage [recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Join-Types_132067691) in order to re-check the merge logic between your tables, aligning to the proper `JOIN` type, as long as keep attention on the comments from @Mikhail Berlyant though, feel free to add here any further investigation results.

Comment: so performing a match between T and B worked.  It was the only thing that did work.  it reduced the runtime back to 8 minutes.  Thanks Mikhail

Answer (score 0):

As per @Mikhail Berlyant recommendations given through the comments, there were suggested the following optimization steps:

- Eliminating cross product joining by adding matching condition:

`ON T.ATTOM_ID = B.ATTOM_ID AND T.some_field = M.some_fiel`;

- Take into the consideration implementing integer range [partition
  tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#integer_range);
- `CAST(UPPER(Field1) AS STRING)` conversion is redundant as `UPPER`
  clause always returns `string` [type](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/UPPER-Function_57344722#syntax).

Composing this answer in order to validate the support, helping the future contributors with their research.